# Why is there a difference between running from install and running from code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've created a C# program that monitors a database and sends via email (and also creates a PDF) a report listing various data. Then, in Visual Studio, I click Build > Publish and go through the steps, then I go to the folder and install the program I just published.

A little info about the data to provide some context: we have multiple devices transmitting data to our database, and the devices are grouped together. Eg, group 1, group 2, etc.

When I run it from the VS window, the report contains data that is correct as near as I can tell. When I run it from the install, the report contains an almost entirely different set of data, including devices from group 10, but there's no group 10 in this database, and no group 10 included in the other report. Other than the report being different, the program seems to be running as expected.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Or where to start troubleshooting? I have no idea where to even start looking for a bug. Or what to google to find an answer? I've tried some things, but I don't understand what's happening well enough to even compose a query for google. Thanks!

Comment: Usually the only fundamental change between the code is that it's published using the Release configuration rather than Debug configuration. Have you added any sort of logging to your application so you can inspect the flow of the application during execution, or can you remote debug the assembly?

Comment: I attached debugging to the process and ran it, but nothing happened, so I assume that means it ran without bugs? Then I tried inserting a couple breakpoints, but that didn't really tell me anything because I don't actually know where to be looking for problems. Did you have any sort of specific thing to look for in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't comment since I don't have 50 reputation so I'll have to post it here...

As @gunr2171 mentioned, if it's publishing, it's going to use the Release configuration vs the Debug configuration...

since you said that it's including devices from group 10... but there's no group 10 in the database... and it contains an almost entirely different data set... it sounds like the release is looking in a different db than the debug, look into the release config...

here's a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-set-debug-and-release-configurations?view=vs-2019) describing how to do it in VS

Comment: and more information on C# configurations in VS [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/project-settings-for-csharp-debug-configurations?view=vs-2019) and also how to create/edit them [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-edit-configurations?view=vs-2019)

Comment: I've run into similar problems before and wanted to provide what a potential solution was... There's nothing requiring anyone to help each other on this website but people still do... just wanted to help.

Comment: I changed the build config to Release and ran the code, then changed back to Debug and ran it. The two reports are identical and correct, but still vastly different from the installed version. Incidentally, I changed two things (the minutes value of the timer that triggers the report, and the file name of the pdf) then republished and reinstalled and ran it, and group 10 is gone and now there's a bunch of entries from group 2 (group 2 is expected, those entries are not). Each time I've republished, it produces a report that is wrong differently.